# How to properly display in MDI a child side bar and a child form in a Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, mdi

I am trying to layout a MDI having one child side bar form and multiple child forms.

When clicking on arrange button, I am trying to have the layout as appear on the following screenshot (the side bar and the most top opened child displayed side by side):

[image]

**Init the sidebar**

```
sideBarForm = new Form();
sideBarForm.MdiParent = this;    
sideBarForm.Show();
sideBarForm.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
sideBarForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
sideBarForm.Name = "sideBarForm";
```

**Adding new child**

```
Form childForm = new Form();
childForm.MdiParent = this;
childForm.Show();
```

**Arrange the layout**

```
 private void Arrange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    foreach (Form child in MdiChildren)
    {
        if (child.Name != sideBarForm.Name)
        {
            child.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            child.Width = this.ClientRectangle.Width - sideBarForm.Width - 50;
            child.Height = this.ClientRectangle.Height - 150;
        }
    }
 }
```

In order to have the two forms properly side by side, it requires to "play" with the numbers. For the width I removed 50px and for the Height 150px.

What is the correct way to have the two forms side by side?

Note: MDI can contains multiple forms opened so I cannot use SplitContainer or TableLayoutPanel for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mdi window respects to docked content and uses the remaining area for mdi child windows.

So, for the side-bar don't add it as a mdi window, instead add it as a docked window. For the rest of windows add them as mdi child windows:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsMdiContainer = true;
    var sideBar = new Form();
    sideBar.Text = "SideBar";
    sideBar.TopLevel = false;
    sideBar.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
    sideBar.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
    this.Controls.Add(sideBar);

    var f1= new Form();
    f1.Text = "Mdi Child 1";
    f1.MdiParent = this;

    var f2 = new Form();
    f2.Text = "Mdi Child 2";
    f2.MdiParent = this;

    sideBar.Show();
    f1.Show();
    f2.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a mdi form and add a panel into it and set the dock property of the panel to right. It will become like below screen shot:

[image]

Use

```
LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
```

Code on events will be like below screen shot:

[image]

on your MDI form. It will arrange all open forms side by side in MDI window. Final screen shot will be like below:

[image]

Comment: Yes but It will make them same size, not like the screenshot I posted

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two panels (one DockStyle.Right and other DockStyle.Fill), and add child forms to panels, like:

```
        sideBarForm = new Form();
        sideBarForm.MdiParent = this;
        panelRight.Controls.Add(sideBarForm);
        sideBarForm.Show();
        sideBarForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        sideBarForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        sideBarForm.Name = "sideBarForm";


        Form childForm = new Form();
        childForm.MdiParent = this;
        panelLeft.Controls.Add(childForm);
        childForm.Show();
```

Regards!

Comment: Docking them causes problems when resizing the forms

Answer (score 0):

Given the layout you're showing, it should be enough to reset the **`SideBarForm`** width to the desired measure in its Resize event.

Add the `SideBarForm` Form to the `MDIChildren` collection first, Dock it to the side you need it to be, then **`SendToBack()`**. This will give the Toolbar a higher priority in the Docking stack.

The other MDI child Form will be docked to fill the remaining space.
When the `MDIParent` is resized or maximized, the disposition will be maintained.

In the **`MDIParent`** Form:

```
private int sideBarSize = 150;

private void MDIParent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MinimumSize = new Size(sideBarSize * 2, sideBarSize * 2);

    SideBarForm sideBarForm = new SideBarForm(sideBarSize);
    ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();

    sideBarForm.MdiParent = this;
    sideBarForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
    sideBarForm.Size = new Size(sideBarSize, this.ClientRectangle.Height);
    sideBarForm.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
    sideBarForm.SendToBack();
    sideBarForm.Show();

    childForm.MdiParent = this;
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    childForm.Show();
}
```

In `SideBarForm`:

```
private int myWidth = 0;

public SideBarForm() : this(150) { }
public SideBarForm(int MySize) 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.myWidth = MySize;
    this.Width = MySize;
}

private void SideBarForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Width = myWidth;
}
```